# Excel automate, if category = X then copy row and paste into tab X

Tags: excel

I want to create an excel document with a complete list of tasks in 1 tab (all tasks) and the tabs supplier #1, supplier #2, supplier #3.

I have the following columns:

Task | Category (suppliers) | Action | Reference number |

How can I automate when a category matches the same name as a tab it auto copies the complete row and insert this this in the supplier tab?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
Sub CopyRowIfMatchesTab()
Dim category As String
Dim lastTasksRow, lastPasteRow, rowCnt As Long
Dim taskSheet As Worksheet, pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set taskSheet = Sheets("Tasks")
lastTasksRow = taskSheet.Cells(taskSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For rowCnt = 2 To lastTasksRow

    category = taskSheet.Cells(rowCnt, 2).Value
    Set pasteSheet = Nothing

    On Error Resume Next
        Set pasteSheet = Sheets(category)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not pasteSheet Is Nothing Then
        lastPasteRow = pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        taskSheet.Rows(rowCnt).Copy
        pasteSheet.Select
        If lastPasteRow = 1 Then
            pasteSheet.Rows(lastPasteRow).Select
        Else
            pasteSheet.Rows(lastPasteRow + 1).Select
        End If
        pasteSheet.Paste
    End If
Next
End Sub
```